# how to create webhook make it send message then delete it discord.js

Tags: discord.js

i am trying to make a code that makes sorta ghost accounts and what it does is create a webhook with the users username and avatar then sends what i specify then delete the webhook this is what i have so far but it doesnt seem to work

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'say',
    cooldown:5,
    description: 'says anything incliding nitro emotes',
    execute(message, args) {
        msg = args.join(" ")

message.channel.createWebhook(`${message.member.username}`, message.author.avatarURL())
  .then(webhook => webhook.send `${msg}`)
  webhook.delete()
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`message.member.createWebhook`'s secone parameter is an object, so replace it with this:

```js
{avatar: message.author.avatarURL()}
```

then, `message.member` doesn't have a username attribute. It is in the `message.author`. So replace `message.member.username` to `message.author.username`.

Then, there is a missing () at `webhook.send`. So replace it with `webhook.send(msg)`.

Finally, `webhook.delete` is outside the promise callback, so `webhook` is not defined there. So move it inside the promise callback will resolve it.

So replace the code from `message.channel.createWebhook` to `webhook.delete` to the following code:

```js
message.channel.createWebhook(message.author.username, {avatar: message.author.avatarURL()}).then(webhook => {
webhook.send(msg).then(() => {
webhook.delete();
});
});
```